# Браузер не реагирует на мышь и клавиатуру

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файлы, firefox, chromium

Относительно недавно заметил такую странную вещь. После указания папки загрузки или любого другого взаимодействия с файловым менеджером в линуксе, браузер перестает реагировать на любые действия, при этом остаётся полностью рабочим, данная проблема только у браузеров на движке Chromium, Firefox же вообще не даёт открыть проводник.

Comment: Можете конкретизировать вашу проблему? Как минимум какая у вас версия Ubuntu и браузеров. Сейчас очень сложно понять, в чём именно может быть проблема.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Ubuntu 22.04, проблема на любом браузере под Chromium возникает.

Comment: В чем причина проблемы, честно говоря, не знаю

Comment: Вангую очередное снаподерьмо )

Comment: Это какое то колдунство, но после запуска Стима или перехода в энергосберегающий режим проблема пропала, ахах